# Parsing DateTime from fixed length String with optional leading zero

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to parse some Strings to Joda DateTime objects like that:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM dd yyyy h:mma");
DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime(dateStr);
```

`dateStr` can be in one of the following formats:

```
"Apr  5 2017  8:11PM"
"Oct 20 2017 10:29PM"
```

Parsing fails with the first String because the given pattern expects to have a leading zero for the day (expects `"05"` and not `" 5"`).

Is there a pattern which could parse both of this date Strings?

Comment: It's not failing because of the missing zero, it's failing because of the extra space. `dd` parses `5` just fine.

Comment: If you can use Java's `java.time` library, a pattern like `"MMM [ ]d yyyy [ ]h:mma"` will work, marking optional space characters in between pattern letters.